# Failed to launch Pixel 5 API 31: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, mobile-application, avd-manager

I use AVD manager to get an emulator for Vscode. When I try to open the emulator,I receive this message: 'Failed to launch Pixel 5 API 31: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds' often, and the emulator failed to open.

To start the emulator, I have to go to the Android Studio AVD manager and wipe the data. After wiped the data, the emulator opens. It's irritating because every time I have to wipe data in order to open the emulator. What is the problem? Give me the solution.

I appreciate your help!